# Slurm - How to automatically set --mail-user to current user?

Tags: slurm

I have a SLURM file e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -n 1                    # two cores
#SBATCH --mem=1G                # RAM
#SBATCH --time=01:99:99         # total run time limit (HH:MM:SS)
#SBATCH --mail-user=rylansch
#SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL


python foo.py
```

I'd like to share this file without needing to manually change the mail-user. How can I do this? If I replace `#SBATCH --mail-user=rylansch` with `#SBATCH --mail-user=$USER`, will that work?

Answer (score 2):

The Bash variable `$USER` will not be expanded in comments so you cannot use it in `#SBATCH --mail-user=$USER`.

But the documentation states

> --mail-user= User to receive email notification of state changes as defined by --mail-type. The default value is the submitting user.

so you can try not specifying `--mail-user` at all (but of course still specify `--mail-type=FAIL`)